# quickfix.Message.getField method

Tags: java, quickfix

I am iterating over a quickfix Message. For a given field, how do I fetch the value for that field without knowing the type? 
The quickfix.Message has methods like '`Double getDouble(int field), String getString(int field)`' etc also, methods like `DoubleField getField(DoubleField), StringField getField(StringField )` etc.
I was expecting a method like '`Object get(int field)`' which returns Object 
How do i retrieve the value without knowing the field type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Short answer:** `getString(int field)` is actually the generic method you're looking for.  You can call it on any field that is present.  Because when you think about it, a FIX message is just a bunch of fields serialized to strings and concatenated, right?

**Longer answer:** FIX messages, internally, just store the fields as strings.  When you store a field to a Message, it doesn't keep your Field object references; it just stores it as a string again.  Similarly, when a message is received, it doesn't allocate a bunch of new Field objects... that's a waste of time and memory.  The field objects are created on-demand when you query for them, and non-string fields are converted when you query for them.

When you call `getInt()`, what actually happens is that the method extracts the field's string value and converts it to an int then returns it.  Similarly, for `getField(IntField)`, it extracts the string, converts it to int, then constructs a new IntField and returns that.

All fields are sent to you from the counterparty as a string.  Thus, `getString(int field)` is perfectly generic, and gives you all the information about the field that there is.